# Aggregate ordinal and binary data according to cluster in R

Tags: r, aggregate, cluster-analysis, r-daisy

I performed k-medoid clustering analysis using `CRAN cluster` package with R. The data is on a `data.frame` called df4 with 13111 obs. of 11 binary and ordinal values. After clustering, I applied the cluster results to the original `data.frame` showing corresponding cluster number to user id.

**How do I aggregate the binary and ordinal choices according to cluster?**

For example, `Gender` variable has male/female values and `Age` ranges from  "18-20", "21-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", and "65+”. I want the sum of the male and female values per cluster for variable `Gender` and for the categories in `Age`.

Here’s the head of my data.frame with cluster label column:

```
#12 variables because I added the clustering object to the data.frame
#I only included two variables from the R output
> str(df4)
'data.frame':   13111 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Age                  : Factor w/ 7 levels "18-20","21-24",..: 6 6 6 6 7 6 5 7 6 3 ...
 $ Gender            : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 …

#I only included three variables from the R output
> head(df4)
     Age    Gender   
1   55-64 Female          
2   55-64 Female          
3   55-64   Male          
4   55-64   Male          
5     65+   Male          
6  55-64 Female
```

Here’s a reproducible example similar to my dataset:

```
age <- c("18-20", "21-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "65+")
gender <- c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female")
smalldf <- data.frame(age, gender)
#Import cluster package
library(cluster)
#Create dissimilarity matrix
#Gower coefficient for finding distance between mixed variable
smalldaisy4 <- daisy(smalldf, metric = "gower", 
                     type = list(symm = c(2), ordratio = c(1))) 
#Set randomization seed
set.seed(1)
#Pam algorithm with 3 clusters 
smallk4answers <- pam(smalldaisy4, 3, diss = TRUE)
#Apply cluster IDs to original data frame
smalldf$cluster <- smallk4answers$cluster
```

**Desired result of output (hypothetical):**

```
  cluster female male 18-20 21-24 25-34 35-44 45-54 55-64 65+
1 1       1      1    1     2     1     0     3     1     0
2 2       2      1    1     1     0     1     2     0     0
3 3       0      1    1     1     1     1     0     2     3
```

Let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: `head=TRUE` makes no sense, and you have a lot of "smart-quotes" that will cause the parser to choke. You should also post what you think is a "correct answer", especially if it not just `with(df4, table(gender, cluster))`

Comment: I've removed the smart quotes and <s from the reproducible code.

Comment: @BondedDust I included a hypothetical answer for the aggregation and made a reproducible example with clustering.

Comment: @MichaelDavidson I keep forgetting these quotation marks from my keyboard wont work. Thanks!

Comment: It's not your keyboard, it's your editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to display the two tables from a cluster-by-gender and a cluster-by-age tabluation in one matrix:

```
 with( smalldf, cbind(table(cluster, gender), table(cluster, age)  ) )
#----------------
  Female Male 18-20 21-24 25-34 35-44 45-54 55-64 65+
1      2    0     1     1     0     0     0     0   0
2      0    4     0     0     1     1     1     1   0
3      1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   1
```